# small size javascript/jquery price range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to use a price range slider in my site, please suggest me a small size yet powerful slider, I've already tried

[noUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) -- did not use this one because it doesn't have percentage option, say you have a range of 0 to 100. my requirement is to reach value `50` at 75% fill.

[JSSlider](http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/) -- almost everything is fine in this slider but size is very big and I have to include almost 15kb of scripts and css.

[JQ UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) -- again I've add one more script for this.

please suggest me a good plug-in or please give me some tutorial links so that I can follow them and get to know how to create your own price slider.

Comment: noUiSlider does support the "reach value 50 at 75% fill" requirement. Set the `range` option to `[ 0, 67 ]`.

Comment: To clarify: ( 100 * 50 ) / 75 ≈ 67

Answer (score 1):

Totally absolutely minimal HTML-only range slider:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```

And a jQuery based polyfill for browsers that don't support it yet: http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion, but the slider you are giving has a single point to slider, I want a slider to which we can select a range from both side, means we can set an min and max range.